# CakePHP 4 SQL function wrapper for min and max returning incorrect data type

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I’m having difficulty with the sql function wrapper in CakePHP 4.  I’m using SQLite 3 and Cakephp 4.2.3 Strawberry.
My database table has a TEXT field called ‘date’.  The smallest and largest values in 'date' are:  '2020-01-15' and '2020-12-31'.  I have a simple query:

```
$query = $this->find();
$query->select(['minDate' => $query->func()->min('date'),
                'maxDate' => $query->func()->max('date')])
      ->where(['date <>' => ''])
      ->enableHydration(false);
       
$results = $query->toList();

$maxDate = $results[0]['maxDate'];
$minDate = $results[0]['minDate'];
```

Which generates the SQL that I want:

```
SELECT (MIN(date)) AS minDate, (MAX(date)) AS maxDate FROM temp_income TempIncome WHERE date <> :c0
```

However the code is returning 'float' values for $minDate and $maxDate:

```
$minDate = 2020
$maxDate = 2020
```

If I run this statement directly in SQLite Studio, I get the correct result (putting '' in for :c0)

```
minDate = '2020-01-15' 
maxDate = '2020-12-31'
```

If I run the query in CakePHP using the Connection Manager, and the same SQL, I get the right answer.

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute("SELECT min(date) as minDate, max(date) as maxDate from temp_income where date <> ''")->fetchAll('assoc');


minDate = '2020-01-15'
maxDate = '2020-12-31'
```

The cake function wrapper `func()->min(‘date’)` is doing an unwanted type conversion.

Digging deeper,  inside vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/database/FunctionsBuilder.php, the builders for min and max are set to return ‘float’ if no other type is defined, which apparently it isn’t in this case.  I don’t know why. I haven't dug that far yet.

```
public function max($expression, $types = []): AggregateExpression
{
    return $this->aggregate('MAX', $this->toLiteralParam($expression), $types, current($types) ?: 'float');
}


public function min($expression, $types = []): AggregateExpression
{
    return $this->aggregate('MIN', $this->toLiteralParam($expression), $types, current($types) ?: 'float');
}
```

The correct behavior for min() and max(), at least in Oracle and SQL Server, and clearly in SQLite because the raw query works fine, is to return the data type of the argument.

Is this a bug in the CakePHP function wrapper?  Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: The `min` and `max` functions take a second parameter, being an array of the types. I can't find an example of this being used in the documentation, I'd guess `->min('date', ['date'])`?

Answer (score 2):

Greg Schmidt is correct.  min() and max() do both accept a type argument.  You need to dig into the documentation for the FunctionsBuilder class to find it:
https://api.cakephp.org/4.1/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html#min

In my case:

```
  $query->select(['minDate' => $query->func()->min('date', ['text']),
                  'maxDate' => $query->func()->max('date', ['text'])])
```

In retrospect, this is clear from the function declarations I posted earlier:

```
public function max($expression, $types = []): AggregateExpression
```

The code above solved the problem.